# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a template in my javascript that will act as the html for a "load-more" widget.  I want to replace certain variables in the template with dynamic data I have pulled from the database.  I am trying to replace the variable "id" in a specific div with the dynamic data.  Here is the code:

Template:

```
var likes_template = '<div class="activity_sub_header">You want <span class="stage_name"></span> to play {{Auth::user()->city}}!</div>'
               +'<br>'
               +'<div class="description">'
               +'<div class="activity_body">description ... <a href="/artists/id">See more...</a></div>'
               +'</div>'
               +'<div class="image"><a href="/artists/id"><img src="image_path" alt="" height="80" width="80" class="img-rounded"></a>'
               +'</div>'
               +'<br><br><br>';
```

Dynamic Replacement:

```
for (like in likes){
            // Clone the element
            var $like = $(likes_template).clone();
            $like.attr('id', 'like-' + likes[like].ID);

var $imgId = $like.find('div.image');
            $imgId.html($imgId.html().replace('id', likes[like].id));

}
```

As you can tell from the code, I am trying to replace the variable "`id`" in the `div class="image"`.  However, when running this, I am getting the error in the title:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined in jquery
```

I have been able to replace other variables with this method, but not this one.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div.image` is not a descendant of the selector element.

But it is one of the sibling.

You would need to use `filter`

```
$like.find('div.image');
```

Supposed to be

```
$like.filter('div.image');
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)